# Добавление элемента в существующий список

Tags: prolog

Хочу чтобы предикат answer возвращал список с добавленным элементом

```
add(E,[],[E]). 
add(E,[H|T],[H|T1]):-add(E,T,T1).
answer(List) :- add( Str, List, NewList), List = NewList.
```

Но что-то не получается...

```
answer(Ct, List, Answers) :-   (Ct > 4),! ; write('Input answer '), write(Ct), write(': '), read(Str), add( Str, List, Answers),
  Ct1 is Ct + 1, answer(Ct1, Answers, Answers).
```

Тут в чём и подвох, я бы рад использовать repeat и избавиться от рекурсивного вызова, но как тогда быть со счётчиком.

Comment: А кто такой answer? Ваш add вполне справляется с добавлением элемента в хвост списка. Что Вы ещё хотите?

Comment: это кусок кода, который заполняет входящий пусток список -list, я убрал ввод str.
соответственно хочу вынести результат

Comment: Я не понимаю. Жаргоном прологеров не владею.

Comment: А по моему здесь фигурирует Str. Где она убрана? Куда вынести результат? Результат чего? Пока такие вопросы.

Comment: @alexlz это типа вывод списка результирующего, я так понял:-)

Answer (score 1):

`=` в Прологе обозначает унификацию, а не присвоение значения. Ваш предикат `answer` не работает т.к. унификация `List = NewList` является ложью (список после добавления элемента не может быт; унифицирован со списком до добавления элемента). Перепишите предикат `answer` следующим образом:

```
answer(List, NewList) :- add( Str, List, NewList).
```

В Прологе как правило следует разделять входные и выходные значения.

Comment: так  точно заработает:
answer(Str,List, NewList) :- add( Str, List, NewList).